# Visual Studio Code terminal displays more than program output

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

New to Visual Studio Code.  I'm using it with python.  For some reason, I get more than just the output of the program when I run python scripts. Looks like it's changing directories and passing arguments. (see screenshot). Not seeing this anywhere else.  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBnED.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBnED.jpg)

Update:

Here is launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Experimental: Terminal (integrated)",
            "type": "pythonExperimental",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "port": 3000,
            "secret": "my_secret",
            "host": "localhost"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Terminal (integrated)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Terminal (external)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload",
                "--nothreading"
            ],
            "debugOptions": [
                "RedirectOutput",
                "Django"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask (0.11.x or later)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "${workspaceFolder}/app.py"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "module.name"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Pyramid",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/development.ini"
            ],
            "debugOptions": [
                "RedirectOutput",
                "Pyramid"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Watson",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/console.py",
            "args": [
                "dev",
                "runserver",
                "--noreload=True"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: All debug Options",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "module": "module.name",
            "env": {
                "VAR1": "1",
                "VAR2": "2"
            },
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "args": [
                "arg1",
                "arg2"
            ],
            "debugOptions": [
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How do you launch you program? Show your `launch.json`.

Comment: see update w/ code